# The use of "to riot in understatement"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "to riot in understatement"? Can you paraphrase it? I include 3 examples from Gore Vidal:

1. In the spring of 1948 I was twenty-two and my third book, "The City and the Pillar", was a bestseller. The remittance crowd was not friendly, **to riot in understatement**, nor were certain far-flung recipients of the Bird's letter.
2. From then on, in public and private, he often behaved boorishly (**to riot in understatement**).
3. Yet do I find it perceptible – here **to riot in understatement** – that I, who was once a leading personage in and about those scanty playgrounds of human interest which we nickname literature seem now to have become, for all practical results, unheard-of thereabouts.

Is it close to "euphemistically speaking" or "to say the least"?

Comment: It's not a phrase I've read before but "to say the least" is certainly a close match in the given examples.

Answer (score 1):

Read *to riot* as *to revel*, *to indulge*, or something similar, and you'll get the gist: it's a writerly aside, expressing how he is reveling in understatement.

Here is the Oxford English Dictionary, "[riot, v.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/166170)," I.3.a, with the latest example:

> a. To take great delight or pleasure in something; to revel in. Now rare.
>
> 1920   South Atlantic Q. Apr. 170   Ward **rioted in** misery and comforted himself with reflections on the general stupidity and perverse worthlessness of by far the major part of mankind.

**To riot in** has a sense of taking pleasure irrespective of one's own better interest. Hence Merriam-Webster adds a sense of *wantonness* ([verb, def. 2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/riot)):

> 2 : to indulge in **revelry** or **wantonness**

So when Vidal employs this as his own turn of phrase, he suggests both that he is engaging in understatement and that he is playing. So it's somewhat like "to say the least," but more verbose,  literary, and even wanton.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase *to riot in understatement* is a witty [*oxymoron*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxymoron), combining a verb suggesting disorder, lack of restraint, even violence and a noun meaning the virtual opposite. The boring standard equivalent would be *to put it mildly*, only much stronger.

So the result of *not friendly* after rioting in understatement would yield something like *aggressively hostile*, *boorish* would become *revoltingly vulgar* or some such.